# Getting Duplicated Primary Keys when combining multiple tables (Full Join)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables (each representing a month) that just have 2 columns (Server and Rating). I just want to group on the Server name, then have a column for each month's rating. I don't know why it is duplicating the servers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The goal is to have:

```
Server   | 1910 | 1911 | 1912 | 2001
---------+------+------+------+-----
abcds    | 2394 | Null | 2332 | 2332
```

Code:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN A.[server] IS NOT NULL THEN A.[server] 
        ELSE (CASE 
                 WHEN B.[server] IS NOT NULL THEN B.[server] 
                 ELSE (CASE 
                          WHEN C.[server] IS NOT NULL THEN C.[server] 
                          ELSE (CASE 
                                   WHEN D.[server] IS NOT NULL THEN D.[server] 
                                   ELSE NULL 
                                END) 
                       END) 
              END) 
  END) AS Server, 
  D.[rating_configured] AS Rating_Config_1910, 
  C.[rating_configured] AS Rating_Config_1911, 
  B.[rating_configured] AS Rating_Config_1912, 
  A.[rating_configured] AS Rating_Config_2001, 
  (CASE 
      WHEN A.[rating_configured] IS NOT NULL THEN A.[rating_configured] 
      ELSE (CASE 
               WHEN B.[rating_configured] IS NOT NULL THEN B.[rating_configured]
               ELSE (CASE 
                        WHEN C.[rating_configured] IS NOT NULL THEN C.[rating_configured] 
                        ELSE (CASE 
                                 WHEN D.[rating_configured] IS NOT NULL 
                                    THEN D.[rating_configured] 
                                    ELSE NULL 
                              END) 
                    END) 
           END) 
     END) AS Most_Recent_Rating_Config 
FROM   
    [Jason_Orf].[dbo].[monthly_server_config_2001] A 
FULL JOIN 
    [dbo].[monthly_server_config_1912] B ON A.[server] = B.[server] 
FULL JOIN 
    [dbo].[monthly_server_config_1911] C ON A.[server] = C.[server] 
FULL JOIN  
    [dbo].[monthly_server_config_1910] D ON A.[server] = D.[server]
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if any of those tables have more than one entry for a particular server?

Comment: Note: I want to include all servers, even if they dont have a value (not present) in the latest month

Comment: I would recommend using COALESCE instead of those massive case expressions. My guess for the duplication is you have multiple rows in some or all of those tables for the join predicates.

Comment: Also, since "A" may omit servers, I am not exactly sure what will happen with the B, C, and D records without a match in A; you may need a subquery to collect the server names from all four tables, and then left join those tables to that. Otherwise every B without an A may be combined with every C without an A, and so on. ....or alternatively, C needs to join to A and B; and D needs to join to A, B, and C.

Comment: I checked through the tables, it appears none have duplicates... its only after I join them do I get duplicated server names.

Comment: Full Join, being joined on `[Server]` is likely culprit. If the same `[Server]` exists in multiple tables, and that's what you're joining on, that's why you're getting duplicates. If there are no other unique identifiers to help distinguish unique rows, you may be better off using a `UNION` to get your results.

Comment: @jw11432 you wouldn't get multiple rows returned unless the same server name exists on more than 1 row in one of the tables. If they have at most 1 occurrence then they would only get a single row.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]

Comment: @Sean Lange Agreed, and I am assuming the server name exists on more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Since full outer joins like that can end up with less than intuitive behavior, it can be best to first gather all relevant `server` values in a subquery, and then LEFT JOIN the relevant tables to that master list:

```
SELECT servers.server
   , D.[rating_configured] AS Rating_Config_1910, 
   , C.[rating_configured] AS Rating_Config_1911, 
   , B.[rating_configured] AS Rating_Config_1912, 
   , A.[rating_configured] AS Rating_Config_2001, 
FROM (
    SELECT server FROM [monthly_server_config_2001]
    UNION SELECT server FROM [monthly_server_config_1912]
    UNION SELECT server FROM [monthly_server_config_1911]
    UNION SELECT server FROM [monthly_server_config_1910]
) AS servers
LEFT JOIN [monthly_server_config_2001] AS A ON servers.server = A.server
LEFT JOIN [monthly_server_config_1912] AS B ON servers.server = B.server
LEFT JOIN [monthly_server_config_1911] AS C ON servers.server = C.server
LEFT JOIN [monthly_server_config_1910] AS D ON servers.server = D.server
;
```

If you still get multiple result rows for a server name, then the server name is not unique in at least one of those tables.

---

The problem with using FULL OUTER JOIN in your original query is that when there are B and C with server name "foo" but A does not have "foo", B and C produce different result rows. This is most easily illustrated with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES ('A'), ('B')) AS A(server)
FULL JOIN (VALUES ('B'), ('C')) AS B(server) ON A.server = B.server
FULL JOIN (VALUES ('C'), ('D')) AS C(server) ON A.server = C.server
;
```